# How to desaturate and blur the game world when paused in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, graphic-effects, blueprints, post-processing

I am creating the pause menu for my game. I want the screen to turn black and white and blurry when it is paused,  much like Left4Dead. But the only special effect I can find is background blur. How can I do this?

I'm using Blueprints in Unreal Engine 4.26

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to apply post process settings to the camera and lower the saturation.
[image: Blueprint example for desaturating camera]
To enable the saturation pin, click on the make node and enable it in the details panel.

[image: Example for enabling pin in post-process node]

Alternatively, instead of applying it to the camera, you could add a post-process component and apply the effects there.